# How can I find out how many edits I've made?

Tags: support

I am curious to know the number of edits I have made to questions, answers and comments of all time on Ask Ubuntu, where do I get this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to your profile and click the *Activity* tab. Under that, click the *Revisions* tab. Those are your edits. Above them (and on the left) it says the total number you've made on the site.

This **does not include edits made to comments**, nor does it include suggested edits that were rejected (though you can look at all your suggested edits--accepted and rejected--in the *Suggestions* tab).

I believe edits to comments are not tracked by the system--or, if they are, that they are accessible only to Stack Exchange developers/employees. We don't have access to comment editing histories or deleted comments, so it seems unlikely that comment edits are tracked the way edits on questions, answers, and tag wikis are.

By the way, there is other user-editable content on Ask Ubuntu, too. Leaving out stuff you have to be a moderator to edit--like the FAQ: You can edit chat messages. While arguably that's  not really on Ask Ubuntu (since [chat.stackexchange.com](http://chat.stackexchange.com) is a separate site), it's directly tied to AU, so I should mention that *it is also not included*. You can also edit your profile (which definitely constitutes AU content), and the number of edits there is not tracked either.

[image: User's profile, showing the number of revisions (edits).]

As I write this, you currently have 76 edits (this is the total for questions, answers, and tag wikis).

Comment: This is simply great! Had never seen this tab before it seems :P

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't find it in the profile section, so to the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/98827/find-out-how-many-edits-ive-made)! Enter your userid (in your case 72576) and run the query.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Marco! That was really helpful. Can you share with with me where can I learn to do this?

Comment: This doesn't include comment edits though, does it? Also, you may want to edit this to mention that the data explorer lags behind the site because it uses snapshots, so for users who are more than minimally active, the number of edits will always be reported as somewhat lower than it really is.